# Avoid element wrapping in tr th in Firefox

Tags: css

Span inside the div drops to the next line, div is nested inside thead tr th, in Firefox. How to avoid that?
The code works in Chrome and IE.

**My Html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><div>2016<span >span</span></div></th>
            <th><div>2017<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span></div></th>
            <th><div>2018<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span></div></th>
         </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**My Css**

```
table thead tr th {
    text-align:right;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
table thead tr th div span {
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
```

see in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karin/zarge854/6/)

Comment: This works for first span but if there is jQuery UI .ui-icon class added which has display set to block then that too needs to be overridden to display:inline-block. Not sure if there is better way.. I accept the answer since I didn't specify ui-icon class. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove span from that group.

Try this.

```
table thead tr th div  {
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zarge854/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zarge854/9/)**

```
table thead tr th div+span{
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
```

For more info check here **[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**